# How to make pen style show up correct in QGIS map composer legend?

Tags: qgis, legend

As far as I can tell, yes I've updated the legend. See new screenshot. It's like the field width is cutting them, they all begin with one long and then one short line.. 
[image]

I have a several different line shapes files that represent buss lines. When I set "Pen style" to different styles I see the changes on the map but it doesn't appear correct in the legend in QGIS map composer.

Fix or work around needed! Using QGIS 2.0 on Mac.
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you update the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Item Properties section of the Print Composer you will see an option for "Symbol". It looks like if you change the Symbol Width in that section you will be able to see the legend better.